# debian wifi setup for failover

Tags: debian, wifi

I do have a small pc(router_office) that runs `debian` `wheezy` (7) and it gets internet from wlan0 and acts as router for eth0 (NAT). Everything works fine.
My setup is pretty simple in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.49
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.2.255
gateway 192.168.2.1
    wpa-ssid "ATUX_wifi"
    wpa-psk "passw0rd4!"
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

I have an second wifi that i could get connected to, which has SSID:be_sec_office with passwd:passwfoo

While in my laptop `debian` 7 with lxde in the connection manager if one wifi fails, then it connects automatically to the next one. How can I do that in my small pc(router_office), please?

Comment: Please tell me that you didn't post your real WiFi passwd!

Comment: no it is not real ssids/passwds. just for the sake of example.

Answer (score 1):

You have to switch from *Managed mode* to *Roaming mode*. It consist of defining your WiFi networks in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` and using logical interfaces in `/etc/network/interfaces`. To adapt the example from `/usr/share/doc/wpasupplicant/README.Debian.gz` (which is a good read), write something like

```
network={
    ssid="ATUX_wifi"
    psk="passw0rd4!"
    id_str="ATUX"
}
network={
    ssid="be_sec_office"
    psk="passwfoo"
    id_str="sec"
}
```

into `/etc/network/interfaces` and

```
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-driver wext
    wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface ATUX inet static
    address 192.168.2.49
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.2.255
    gateway 192.168.2.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

iface sec inet static
    address ...
    ...
```

into `/etc/network/interfaces` (besides the current `lo` and `eth0` definition).